# AIX - Cannot create VM thread. Out of system resources

Tags: java, bash, unix, heap-memory, aix

We have a batch job that runs smoothly on Java 6. However, I'm trying to update it to Java 8 but throws the error below.

> Error occurred during initialization of VM Cannot create VM thread.
>
> Out of system resources.

Here's a snippet of the batch job.

```
execute $JAVA_HOME/bin/java -Xmx2500m -classpath $CLASSPATH org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner app-context/main-context.xml
```

The machine I'm using is Unix AIX.

```
$uname -a
AIX <servername> 2 7 00CBE6574C00
```

Java 8 has been installed on the machine. JAR file is also compiled to Java 8.

```
$java -version
java version "1.8.0_221"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 8.0.5.41 - ### (SR5 FP41))
IBM J9 VM (build 2.9, JRE 1.8.0 AIX ppc64-64-Bit Compressed References ### (JIT enabled, AOT enabled)
```

I was thinking that it could be a heap size issue so I played with the max heap size from -Xmx64m to -Xmx5000m. However, the error still persists.

Here's the system current limits:

```
$ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 1048575
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) 131072
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) 32768
open files                      (-n) 40961
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 64
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 32768
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) unlimited
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
```

I'm new to unix. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking for a VM with 2.5G heap space (-Xmx2500m), but you only allow 32M memory (max memory size 32786kb = 32MB).

Try increasing the max memory to (at least) 2.6G. You will need slightly more that what you specify for the heap to accommodate VM fixed cost.

Comment: Thanks, Dash. However, i don't think that's the problem as it has been running smoothly on Java 6 using -Xmx2500m with max memory size 32786kb. There was no environment change except on upgrading it to Java 8.

Comment: Kindly try it with bigger `ulimit` values: it's no secret that newer programs eat more memory than older ones.

Answer (score 0):

try updating the java application again. it would work for sure. or increase memory VRA